# use Trigger to update the column number

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

Now i am trying to use trigger to update the number which is below 2. But i have try many times. After changed, the trigger can run without any error. But when i execute it, the number still cannot update yet for the row which have number below 2.
Here is my code

```
create or replace trigger incrate
after update on student
for each row

BEGIN
update student 
set Score = 20
where Score < 2;

END;
/
```

Here is sample table

```
Sid Score
A1  1
A2  62
A3  25
A4  0
```

Assume that I would like to change the output to make the Score below 2 to 20.
So, after i execute it, i use `select count(*) from student where Score =1;`.
The output should be `0`.

Can give some suggestion to me to change this command and thanks for advice.

Comment: Trigger syntax is highly dependent on what database you are using.  Please add the appropriate tag.  My guess is that you are using `oracle` based on the code you've posted but maybe you copied code from an Oracle reference and are really using a different database.  It is also very helpful to explain what isn't working-- are you getting an error?  If so, what error?  A runtime error?  Or a compilation error?

Comment: I can run the trigger without any errror. But the column data still can no change.

Comment: Show us an example of what you are doing and what you are seeing.  If you're using Oracle, I would have expected you would be getting a mutating table exception.  Since you're not, you must be doing something different than I'm guessing you're doing.  If you can show us what you're doing, it is much more likely that we can help.

Comment: What about a ___before update___ trigger that contains an `IF`, i.e. `IF new.SCORE < 2 THEN new.SCORE = 20` (check the syntax since I'm not 100% certain that it is correct)

Comment: Would you mind telling what is it you want to achieve ? In a each row trigger you are updating first the same table which will cause to mutating error ? And second your update doesn't depend on row so why not go for statement level trigger ?

Comment: @user12717227, Would you please execute the below statement and post the result here ?  SELECT BANNER FROM V$VERSION.

Comment: @Ranagal, here is the output `Oracle Database 18c Express Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production`

Comment: Depending on the version the handling of this scenario changes. If you really want to handle this in a trigger then you should tell us why so ? Because you can issue a direct update statement on student table for any update like this and for sure it works.

Comment: @user12717227, Ok, now that you are saying it is indeed an Oracle DB. You definitely would have got an error while executing this trigger as what you are doing is a perfect example for mutating trigger problem. Now, tell us why you can't issue an update statement and change all the scores at once like what is already told by Tim?

Answer (score 0):

Your trigger on the `student` table also is attempting to update the same table.  This is a recursive trigger, and isn't even allowed on some databases.  Instead of using a trigger, I would suggest incorporating this logic into your update:

```
UPDATE student
SET ...
    Score = CASE WHEN Score < 2 THEN 20 ELSE Score END
WHERE ...
```

Comment: thank for answering but ur code still cannot change the number.

Comment: Yes, it _will_ certainly change the value of `Score`.